# Configure New Server for .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I have a new LAMP CENTOS 5 server I am setting up and trying to copy the configuration from another web server I have.  I am stuck with what I think is a mod_rewrite problem.
If I go to http://old-server.com/any_page_name.php it correctly routes through some handling code in index.php and shows me a graceful "Page Cannot Be Displayed" message.

But if I go to http://new-server.com/any_page_name.php I get an ugly Apache 404 Not Found error message.

I looked in both httpd.conf files and they both have only one reference to mod_rewrite.
   **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**
So it seems like that should be fine.

At the bottom of httpd.conf I have the code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName new-server.com
  ErrorLog logs/new-server.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/new-server.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in the root of /var/www/html I have the exact same .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page-unavailable/

<files ~ "\.tpl$">
order deny,allow
allow from none
deny from all
</files>
```

So I don't see why the page load at old-server.com works fine while new-server.com doesn't route through index.php like I want it to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set the `AllowOverride All` option to allow .htaccess files.

On a sidenote:
Maybe you should think about moving the server logic into the server config.